# Method to find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[5]{n^3 + 3 \sqrt[5]{n^2}+1} - \sqrt[5]{n^3 + 2 \sqrt[5]{n}+1}}{1-\cos(\frac{3}{n})}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have the following limit:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[5]{n^3 + 3 \sqrt[5]{n^2}+1} - \sqrt[5]{n^3 + 2 \sqrt[5]{n}+1}}{1-\cos\left(\dfrac{3}{n}\right)}$$

I know that it should be $\dfrac{2}{15},$ however I could not find the method to solve it.

I had a hint to use Heine, so I think it can be rewritten as the limit of the function but I could not see how it can help me. I tried L'Hôpital's rule and also used $A^5 - B^5 = (A - B)(B^4 + B^3A + B^2A^2 + BA^3 + A^4),$ but nothing seems to help. I think I am missing some trick using standard (known) limits.

Comment: Are you sure you have voth $x$ and $n$ in that expression?

Comment: sry, just $ n $, will fix it

Comment: The help the formula provides is that when you rewrite the expression as a product the 'goes to zero''  part appears as a factor so it becomes easier to get rid of it. At the same time, the remaining factor most generally does not converge to zero so it is easy to state it in a much simplifies way after applying some equivalences (in the case it went to zero you would apply the analog formula for the correspondent degree and so on...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$2+\frac{2}{5}=\frac{3\cdot4}{5},$$ by your work we obtain: $$\frac{\sqrt[5]{n^3 + 3 \sqrt[5]{n^2}+1} - \sqrt[5]{n^3 + 2 \sqrt[5]{n}+1}}{1-\cos(\frac{3}{n})}=$$
$$=\frac{3\sqrt[5]{n^2}-2\sqrt[5]{n}}{2\sin^2\frac{3}{2n}\left(\sqrt[5]{\left(n^3 + 3 \sqrt[5]{n^2}+1\right)^4} +...+ \sqrt[5]{\left(n^3 + 2 \sqrt[5]{n}+1\right)^4}\right)}=$$
$$=\frac{n^2\left(3\sqrt[5]{n^2}-2\sqrt[5]{n}\right)}{2\cdot\frac{\sin^2\frac{3}{2n}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\cdot n^{\frac{3\cdot4}{5}}\left(\sqrt[5]{\left(1 + \frac{3 \sqrt[5]{n^2}}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^4} +...+ \sqrt[5]{\left(1 + \frac{2 \sqrt[5]{n}}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^4}\right)}\rightarrow\frac{3}{2\cdot\frac{9}{4}\cdot5}=\frac{2}{15}.$$
I used $$\frac{\sin^2\frac{3}{2n}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{9}{4}\left(\frac{\sin\frac{3}{2n}}{\frac{3}{2n}}\right)^2\rightarrow\frac{9}{4}$$ because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1.$$

Comment: can you please expain how did you get in denominator $\sin^2 \frac{3}{2n} $ and also the  $ \frac{9}{4}$ ?

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of the fundamental limit
$$\frac{(1+\alpha(x))^\gamma-1}{\alpha(x)} \to \gamma,$$
toghether with, of course,
$$\frac{1-\cos\alpha(x)}{\alpha^2(x)}\to \frac12$$
whenever $\alpha(x)\to 0$.
So
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal L &=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[5]{n^3+3\sqrt[5]{n^2}+1}-\sqrt[5]{n^3+2\sqrt[5]{n}+1}}{1-\cos\frac3n}=\\
&\stackrel{\sqrt[5]{n}=t}{=}&\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt[5]{t^{15}+3t^2+1}-\sqrt[5]{t^{15}+2t+1}}{1-\cos\frac{3}{t^5}}=\\
&=&\lim_{t\to \infty}\underbrace{\frac{\frac9{t^{10}}}{1-\cos \frac3{t^5}}}_{\to 2}\cdot\frac{t^{10}}9\cdot t^3 \left[\left(\sqrt[5]{1+\frac{3t^2+1}{t^{15}}}-1\right)-\left(\sqrt[5]{1+\frac{2t+1}{t^{15}}}-1\right)\right]=\\
&=&\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac29\cdot t^{13}\left(\underbrace{\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+\frac{3t^2+1}{t^{15}}}-1}{\frac{3t^2+1}{t^{15}}}}_{\to\frac15}\cdot \frac{3t^2+1}{t^{15}}-\underbrace{\frac{\sqrt[5]{1+\frac{2t+1}{t^{15}}}-1}{\frac{2t+1}{t^{15}}}}_{\to \frac15}\cdot \frac{2t+1}{t^{15}}\right)=\\
&=&\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac2{45}\frac{3t^{15}-2t^{14}}{t^{15}}=\frac2{15}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By the MVT, if $0<x<y,$ then

$$y^{1/5}-x^{1/5} = (1/5)c^{-4/5}(y-x).$$

The expression on the right is bounded below by $(1/5)y^{-4/5}(y-x)$ and bounded above by $(1/5)x^{-4/5}(y-x).$ And of course $1-\cos u \approx u^2/2$ as $u\to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $n=1/t$; if the limit exists for $t\to0$, then it's equal to the limit of the sequence. Then observe that
$$
\sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{t^3}+\frac{3}{t^{2/5}}+1}
=\frac{1}{t^{3/5}}\sqrt[5]{1+3t^{13/5}+t^3}
=\frac{1}{t^{3/5}}\left(1+\frac{3}{5}t^{13/5}+o(t^{13/5})\right)
$$
Similarly,
$$
\sqrt[5]{\frac{1}{t^3}+\frac{3}{t^{1/5}}+1}
=\frac{1}{t^{3/5}}\sqrt[5]{1+3t^{14/5}+t^3}
=\frac{1}{t^{3/5}}(1+o(t^{13/5}))
$$
Therefore the numerator is
$$
\frac{1}{t^{3/5}}\left(\frac{3}{5}t^{13/5}+o(t^{13/5})\right)=\frac{3}{5}t^2+o(t^2)
$$
The denominator is
$$
1-\cos3t=\frac{9t^2}{2}+o(t^2)
$$
and therefore the limit is
$$
\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{9}=\frac{2}{15}
$$

Comment: (+) I like your method.